# Authenticate through oauth server and api key at the same time

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

In Spring Boot, is it possible to authenticate clients using both OAuth2 and API Keys?  Let's say I have an application with UI.  The user logs in the UI and given a jwt token from an OAuth2 server.  So the security config looks like this

```
...
http.authorizeRequests()
    ....
    .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
    .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);
```

The oauth2 server is configured in application.yml file.

Say, I want to expose some of the backend APIs to other clients and only authorized them by authenticating the API Key.  Can I just add a `addFilterBefore` in my security config?  Does it mean it will authenticate both api key and oauth jwt?

```
http.addFilterBefore(new SomeApiKeyFilter(...))
    ....
    .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
    .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);
```

Is this possible? Cause when I tried to call an endpoint, it throws an error saying `... APIKeyAuthenticationToken cannot be cast to JwtAuthenticationToken`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ch4mp told, you have to define two security configurations. I did It by adding two innerclasses (as a configuration) in my security configuration class instead of creating two Beans. Let me show you an example:

```
public class SecurityConfig {

  @Configuration
  @Order(1)
  public static class DefaultSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.securityMatcher("/xxx/**")
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                 .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            ...
            .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);

        return http.build();
    }

  }

  @Configuration
  @Order(2)
  public static class OtherSecurityConfig {

      @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain otherFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.securityMatcher("/yyy/**")
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .formLogin()
            ...;

        return http.build();
    }
  }

}
```

You will get a form login if you try to access the **yyy** base path and 401 http error if you try the **xxx** base path.

Answer (score 1):

The way your question is formulated reflects your configurations issue: a request won't be authorized with an API key and a `Bearer` access token "at the same time". It will be authorized using one or the other, and it should be processed by a different security filter-chains in each case.

So, instead of adding a filter in the existing chain, add another `SecurityFilterChain` bean to your web security configuration.

To have more than one filter chain `@Bean` in an app, it should:

- have different names
- be decorated with distinct `@Order`
- all but the last one in `@Order` contain a `http.securityMatcher(...)` to define which requests it should process (the last one in `@Order` being used as default for all requests that weren't matched)

##### P.S. 1

Instead of API keys, you should seriously consider using OAuth2 `client_credentials` flow, and have a single standard OAuth2 filter-chain processing requests initiated by both

- users (with tokens obtained using `authorization_code`)
- programmatic clients (with tokens obtained using `client_credentials`)

##### P.S. 2

You should check if you have an explicit reference to `JwtAuthenticationToken` in you source code, and also where this `APIKeyAuthenticationToken` comes from (doesn't seem to be part of Spring releases, at least not recent ones). If you configure two security filter-chains `@Bean` and each populates the security context with its own `Authentication` type, you'll have to make your code using this authentications polymorph (or use a common parent class / interface).